# C segmentation fault with methods

Tags: c, compilation, segmentation-fault

I am trying to work with the `setup_diamond()` and `draw_game()` functions and I keep getting a segmentation fault. I have literally no idea why I'm having this error, as far as I am aware, everything is being stored correctly and is initialized.

```
//Function for preparing the diamonds
void setup_diamond() {
    //For loop, the size of the number of max diamonds
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BD; i++){
        //Creates an array which stores the values for the diamond x values
        rand_x_value[i] = rand() % (screen_width()-BD_WIDTH);
        //Creates 10 big diamonds based on the rand angle
        Bdiamond[i] = sprite_create( rand_x_value[i], 3, BD_WIDTH, BD_HEIGHT, Bdiamond_image );
        //Creates a random angle which is saved in an array
        randAngle[i] = rand() % 360;
        //Set's the diamonds speeds to 0.1
        sprite_turn_to (Bdiamond[i], 0.1, 0);
        //Points the diamond in the random direction saved in the array
        sprite_turn (Bdiamond[i], randAngle[i] );
        //Draws the diamond
        sprite_draw (Bdiamond[i] );
        //Creates 20 medium sized diamonds
        for (int q = 0; q <= 20; q++){
        Ldiamond[q] = sprite_create(-5, -5, LD_HEIGHT , LD_HEIGHT, Ldiamond_image);
        }
        //Creates 40 small diamonds
        for (int k = 0; k <= 40; k++){
        Mdiamond[k] = sprite_create(-3, -3, MD_WIDTH , MD_HEIGHT, Mdiamond_image);
        }

    }

}

void draw_game() {
    clear_screen();
    draw_border();
    sprite_draw ( ship );

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BD; i++ ) {
        sprite_draw(Bdiamond[i] );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i <= MAX_BULLET; i++){
        sprite_step(bullet[i]);
        sprite_draw(bullet[i]);
    }
    //Creates 20 medium diamonds at an offscreen position ready for use when diamonds are split
    for( int k = 0; k <= MAX_MD; k++){
        sprite_step(Mdiamond[k]);
        sprite_draw(Mdiamond[k]);
    }
        //Creates 40 small diamonds off screen
    for( int q = 0; q <= MAX_LD; q++){
        sprite_step(Ldiamond[q]);
        sprite_draw(Ldiamond[q]);
    }
}
```

There is a link to my source folder [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1Law3IdbnVqVzhYR3Y5NlVCZkk?usp=sharing)

it includes Code (in 'c') and my library folder. I am compiling using Cygwin.

Comment: What does your debugger have to say about it?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, the debugger doesn't say anything, it gets compiled but after I press a key it gives me a segmentation fault

Comment: Does that then mean that you haven't even tried the debugger?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot in the link I provided of what I think you may mean @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Comment: It says *Assertion: "sprite != NULL" failed ... [file details] ... core dumped*.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. The debugger will tell you _where exactly_ the crash happens, and this will give you valuable information about what is going wrong.

Comment: `Assertion: "sprite != NULL" failed ... [file details] ... core dumped` That is vital information that needs to go in your actual question. It should also tell you immediately that you need to look for a sprite that you have forgotten to initialise. You have passed a null pointer to a sprite function.